# Child Theme functions.php has no effect

Tags: functions, child-theme

I'm trying to make a child theme of Woothemes Appply theme.

The Child functions.php file is having no affect though. I started by adding in the code to enqueue a style sheet, which didn't work. Then I added in a simple echo which didn't work. Finally, I put in junk code to try to break the site, which it didn't.

It seems my functions.php file, which is in my child theme folder, is having no affect whatsoever.

To make sure I'm not doing something fundamentally wrong, I set up a child theme for twentyfifteen in the same way, and it works just fine. There must be something in the Appply parent theme that is preventing the child theme functions.php file from working.

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated!!

Comment: It may be helpful to note that a child theme's `functions.php` file is loaded *before* the parent theme's. Nothing in the parent theme should be able to prevent your child theme from loading because the child is loaded first.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I'm so lost on this. When I typed gibberish into the functions.php file of the child, the site loaded fine with no errors.

Comment: Rather than type gibberish, just put `<?php die( 'The mothership has landed.' ); ?>` at the top. Then you'll know for sure if WordPress is loading it or not ;)

Comment: Just tried that, no effect. I can't understand why it's not loading that file... I've sent a support ticket to Woothemes, but they aren't open until Monday Morning.

Comment: What does the top comment section of your child theme's style.css look like?

Comment: I don't have that child theme intact anymore. I gave up and just renamed the parent theme... the comment was correctly formatted for a child theme though.